# Servlet.service() for servlet LoginController threw exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Decoder.BASE64Encoder

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

Servlet.service() for servlet LoginController threw exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Decoder.BASE64Encoder

```
try{
    String pass=request.getParameter("password");
    String plainData=pass,cipherText,decryptedText;

    KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES"); 
    keyGen.init(128); 

    SecretKey secretKey = keyGen.generateKey(); 
    Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES"); 
    aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,secretKey); 

    byte[] byteDataToEncrypt = plainData.getBytes(); 
    byte[] byteCipherText = aesCipher.doFinal(byteDataToEncrypt); 

    cipherText=new BASE64Encoder().encode(byteCipherText);

    System.out.println("cipherText"+cipherText);
    ld=new LoginDao();

    String encryptedpass=ld.validatepass(cipherText);
    System.out.println();
}
catch(Exception ex){

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `commons-codec`  jar in lib directory of your web project and use

`new Base64().encodeToString(String)` to encode

Your Web application war file structure is like

```
WebContent
    --- WEB-INF
         ----web.xml (Deployment Descriptor)
         ---- lib 
                --- Add your libraries here i.e.common-codec.jar and others
```

Comment: Adding the link http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/

Comment: thanks dude actually i have not imported jar files in webcontainer